# Attaching image to first letter

Tags: html, css

I have a question
How can I attach image to the first letter of H1 using CSS?
See picture
Are there any ideas?
[image]

Comment: use `position:absolute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `:before` pseudo class to attach the image.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8o0z6a8r/1/

```
<sytle>
h1:before {
    content: url(http://placehold.it/50x50);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 20px;
}
</style>

<h1>LINKBOUND's</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: [jsFiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYrogK)

```
<div id="container">
    <h1 class="maintitle">LINKBOUND</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#id{
    position:relative;
}

.maintitle{
    font-size:100pt;
}

.maintitle:before{
   content: url('http://placehold.it/75/75');
  position:absolute;
  top:170px;
}
```